# App crashes without reason with xCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4

Something weird is going on here.
My app crashes on this line of code:

```
int end = NSMaxRange(endRange);
```

but I don't get any error message, and everything is fine: endRange. The app just freezes in the iPhone and that's it.

1.
The weird thing is that the same code was working before, and I've reversed from repository to see what's wrong but it still doesn't work.

2.
Also xCode removes the breakpoint every time the app crashes. I add it again, I run the app, I step over, the app crashes and Xcode removes the breakpoint.

3.
I've cleaned the build, restarted xCode, restarted the iPhone, removed the app from the iPhone. Same issues.

4.
If I don't use breakpoints, the app doesn't crash, but the code right after that line is "skipped", but it was working before. At least the app doesn't freeze without breakpoint.

What the hell ?

Comment: What about `endRange`? Could provide more details?

Comment: Try a computer restart as well as everything else in step 3. From your symptoms, it sounds like an xCode problem, not anything to do with your code.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted endRange.location =186 endRange.length=18

Comment: @mopsled I've restarted the mac, it is the same...

Comment: Quite strange for me. Have you tried to enable exception breakpoints?

Comment: @Flex_Addicted I've just tried to add the exception breakpoints, but there are not thrown exceptions.

Comment: Sorry i've updated my post, I forgot to mention about point 4.

Comment: What specific version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `int end = endRange.location + endRange.length`? And then `NSLog` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems with the debugger in the past too. Try switching from LLDB back to GDB (From the Product / Edit Scheme menu). I've found LLDB to do exactly what you are describing with breakpoints.

Comment: I second that. I've had the same experience. Try it with GDB.